# Send custom confirmation email in Devise depending on role defined in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, confirmation, confirmation-email

I am using Devise for registration of a site with confirmable.  However, I have two different roles for this site.  The first role is the "main" role that uses the regular Devise signup procedure. Accounts in a second role are supposed to be created after the original user confirms their account, logs in for the first time and saves a certain model.  For example, if a user signs up for the site (as role type 1) the get a confirmation email from Devise as normal.  Next, they visit the confirmation link, verify their account and then fill out a form where they specify some friends that should also get accounts. The friends are role type 2 and they should get a different confirmation email than the original person who signed up their friends for the account.  The accounts for the friends are created when the form filled out by the original user is saved.  In addition, a person can edit and add more friends later so accounts might also need to be created on the update method of the relevant form/object and those new users will need to be sent the correct email.  To be clear, I do not want to skip confirmation - I just want to send different confirmation emails to the user depending on their roles.  I cannot figure out how to handle this properly.  If I try to create the friends accounts in code when the form is saved with User.new, calling user.skip_confirmation! will automatically confirm them. However, I do not want anyone automatically confirmed - I just want to select a different customizable confirmation email to send depending on various conditions.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Check out `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions` method and comments for it in your /gems/devise-x.x.x/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb